# AdMob Lib - ClassNotFound

Tags: admob, classnotfoundexception, codenameone

I tried to add the new admobfullscreen-codenameone functionality to my app. But I get a ClassNotFound exception when running the project. Can anyone tell me how to include the library project into my own project. (I did the steps explained in https://github.com/chen-fishbein/admobfullscreen-codenameone)

please help
babür

Comment: Can you post the full trace and your code